# How to reuse generic interface?

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using ASP.NET Boilerplate, on ASP.NET Core.
I have some model classes.

```
public class AClass : FullAuditedEntity<int>
{

}
```

and one interface like below.

```
public interface ISomeInterface<T, TEntity> where T : BaseFileEntity where TEntity : class, IEntity<int>
{

}
```

Now If I add one extra model class like below.

```
public class BClass : FullAuditedEntity<string>
{

}
```

I have to define another interface for this change like below.

```
public interface ISomeInterface<T, TEntity> where T : BaseFileEntity where TEntity : class, IEntity<string>
{

}
```

So basically it's duplicate code. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Well you can add one more generic parameter: `interface ISomeInterface<T, TEntity, TEntityKey> where T : BaseFileEntity where TEntity : class, IEntity<TEntityKey>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to declare your interface like the one below so you can pass the type to IEntity

```
public interface ISomeInterfaceB<T, TEntity, TK> where T : BaseFileEntity where TEntity : class, IEntity<TK> {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Change the interface to:

```
public interface ISomeInterface<T, TEntity, U> where T : BaseFileEntity where TEntity : class, IEntity<U>
{

}
```